# Data imbalance when there is only one output

Tags: keras, lstm

I have data which 3% labeled yes and 97% labeled no. It's a continuous data stream, so I don't think I can force duplicate the yes data. I'm using LSTM where the output is 1 for yes and 0 for no. Also I don't think I can mine for more data. I've found something about class weight but I've no idea how to implement it to this case. Is there any other way to overcome this problem? The data is numerical and continuous.

Answer (score 0):

There is 2 types of solutions that you can adopt.

The first would be to build a data generator that builds batches that pick a balanced number of samples. For instance you can build a python generator that generates batches of 32 samples such that 16 are randomly picked from set 'yes' and 16 are randomly picked from set 'no'. That would mean that the yes samples are seen much more frequently by the model but you are not discarding data as such.

The second class of solutions is to use weights on your metric. i.e. you can feed an array of sample weights to the fit operation such that yes samples have a weight that is much higher for 'yes' samples than for 'no' samples.

You can also implement weighting via a custom metric.

I would start by the approach of writing a data generator.